# How to enable/disable bluetooth in android java?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I tried various things other than this code, but it didn't work properly.

```
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
       
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    try {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }catch(SecurityException d){
        d.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: So what *happens* with is code?  Compilation errors?  An exception? Unexpected behavior.

Comment: Please describe the behavior that you expect and the actual behavior so it's clear how it did not work exactly.

Comment: Why do you want to enable/disable Bluetooth using your app? Imagine someone listening to music via Bluetooth and your app just turns it off. You should tell the user to enable it before using the app to prevent confusion

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result  the using `startActivityForResult` method is no longer recommended.  But if you do use it, you will need to use an `onActivityResult` to wait for the action to complete.

Your current code is not waiting ... so if you immediately try to use Bluetooth you are liable to find that it is still disabled.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using 'onActivityResult' or in another way?
How to do it using 'onActivityResult' ?

Comment: Well ... it depends what "it" is.  `onActivityResult` registers a callback.  The callback can do things.  Whether it can do your thing depends on what your things is.  It can't wait.  But it can signal that something has happened.  But whether that helps will depend on what you want to happen after Wifi has been enabled.